# Why upstart documentation prevents me from using respawn

Tags: upstart, services

In documentation I [found](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn) a note that I shouldn't use respawn if I satisfied with expect.

But I cannot understand, how are they interfere.
For example, nginx [config](http://wiki.nginx.org/Upstart) using both and predictable didn't respawn if I disable the respawn stanza.

So, what "confusing behaviour" should I expect?

Comment: You skipped the key word *until* you are satisfied with the expect stanza.  The reason is that if you get the expect stanza wrong, it will keep trying to respawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't say you can't use both stanzas. It says, to paraphrase, don't include a `respawn` stanza **until you are satisfied your `expect` stanza is working**.

Problems with the `expect` stanza can be very difficult to debug and can be quite disastrous. See the cookbook's entry on the `expect` stanza, especially the section describing whether to use `expect fork` or `expect daemon` for examples of what can happen.